# SUBSTRING_INDEX with multiple delimiters

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove some information off urls that are placed into my database. I have this query that I am using:

```
Select substring_index(refurl,'?gclid',1) as refurl, Count(*)
from leads
group by substring_index(refurl,'?gclid',1)
```

But for the delimiter I really need to take off both of these:

```
?gclid or &gclid
```

Is this possible by doing an OR statement within the substring or is it something completely different to get this done?

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for cleaning it up.  I will make sure I do that before I submit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `IF`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(refurl, IF(LOCATE('?gclid', refurl), '?gclid', '&gclid'), 1) AS refurl, ...
```

Comment: That does not work.  It says unknown column 'a' in field list.  If I change the a to a 1, it only takes away &gclid and not the urls with ?gclid

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it should be `1`.

Comment: But when I changed it to one it didnt take off the urls with ?gclid though only &gclid worked.

Comment: Oops, didn't you notice that I got the arguments to `LOCATE` backwards? Fixed it.

Comment: haha I just figured that out as well.  Thanks again works great now I have them in the right places.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, 
I just needed to group strings before a certain number, ex:

```
hcu
----------------------
AQP Casma 01 HCU 200
AQP Casma 10 HCU 1500
AQP Casma 11 HCU 1500
Cusco 1 HCU 1500
Cusco 2 HCU 200-3
Cusco 3 HCU 200-1
Cusco 12 HCU 200
```

to obtain only this:

```
AQP Casma
Cusco
```

I couldn't use IF because the multiple delimiters, so the query that I've used is:

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(' 0',hcu )>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(hcu, '0', 1)
    WHEN LOCATE(' 1',hcu )>0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(hcu, '1', 1)  
END hub  
FROM npi_hist 
GROUP BY hub
```

And the result was the expected... I don't know why is grouping correctly all the Cusco registers, but It's working as I needed.

Hope it could help.

Bye.