# How to pass multiple delimeters in substring_index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring, relational-database

I want to query the string between https:// or http:// and the first delimeter characters that comes after it. For example, if the field contains:

```
https://google.com/en/
https://www.yahoo.com?en/
```

I want to get:

```
google.com
www.yahoo.com
```

My initial query that will capture the `/` only contains two substring_index as follows:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(mycol,'/',3),'://',-1)
FROM mytable;
```

Now I found that the URLs may contain multiple delimeters. I want my statament to capture multiple delimeters possibilities which are (each one is a separate character):

```
:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

How to do this in my statement? I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521558/substring-index-with-multiple-delimiters) but the end result the command could not be executed due to syntax error while I am sure I followed the solution. Can anyone help me correctly construct the query to capture all the delimeter characters I listed above?

I use MySQL workbecnh 6.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.

**EDIT:**

Some corrections made in the first example of URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that `https://www.yahoo.com?en/` seems like an unlikely URL, because it has a path separator contained inside the query string.  In any case, if you are using MySQL 8+, then consider using its regex functionality.  The `REGEXP_REPLACE` function can be helpful here, using the following pattern:

```
https?://([A-Za-z_0-9.-]+).*
```

Sample query:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'https://www.yahoo.com?en/' AS url UNION ALL
    SELECT 'no match'
)

SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(url, 'https?://([A-Za-z_0-9.-]+).*', '$1') AS url
FROM yourTable
WHERE url REGEXP 'https?://[^/]+';
```

### Demo

The term `$1` refers to the first *capture* group in the regex pattern.  An explicit capture group is denoted by a quantity in parentheses.  In this case, here is the capture group (highlighted below):

```
https?://([A-Za-z_0-9.-]+).*
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is, the capture group is the first portion of the URL path, including domain, subdomain, etc.

Comment: `https://www.yahoo.com?en/  seems like an unlikely URL`. This is just an example. But I have large dataset that contains such syntax or similar..

Comment: Fine.  My answer should handle all of your cases (I think).

Comment: but domain names can contain numbers and dashes. Your `[A-Za-z_.]+` does not capture this.

Comment: Good point, I updated my regex.  You should be able to get away with just a single call to `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: and underscores are also allowed in domain names. Sorry I did not know that but a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it) now says they are legal.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get: Error Code: 1305. `REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist`. I use MysQL workbench 6.3. How to upgrade? I also use Ubuntu 18.04 so you can tell me the required command plz.

Comment: Checkout the [download page for MySQL 8+](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).  If you have a long term need for such regex support, then yes, you should consider upgrading.

Comment: I have `5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2`. I do not want to miss thing. If upgrading can cause issues I have big data. I already downloaded the older version and everything in mydatabase is connected and I already have schemes and data.

Comment: OK...at this point you have potentially 3 valid answers to the question you originally asked.  If you have some upgrade issue, then you should open a new question, possibly on the Ubuntu or SuperUser site.  Good luck!

Comment: I upgraded. But what is '$1' is for? I looked at the manual, it is not clear for me why you are using it? Can you clarify plz.

Comment: & how to ensure that the resulting string that matches the regex is not null? because I added `WHERE url is NOT NULL`, but I got an error saying that no column called url.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.  Use `WHERE col IS NOT NULL`, where `col` is the name of the column containing the URL.

Comment: Please read the above comment again.  Your question deviates from the OP, and changing my answer again would make it less useful for others later on.

Comment: Thanks. But I want the result of the matching is NOT NULL not the col. so in this example I should do: `WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE('https://www.yahoo.com?en/', 'https?://([A-Za-z_0-9.-]+).*', '$1') IS NOT NULL`, I guess?

Comment: @user9371654 Check my updated query.  Use `REGEXP` in the `WHERE` clause to assert that the URL matches.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, this should work:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_substr(mycol, '://[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[/:?]'), '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]', '')
FROM (SELECT 'https://google.com/en' as mycol union all
      SELECT 'https://www.yahoo.com?en'
     ) x
```

In older versions, this is much more challenging because there is no way to search for a string class.

One brute force method is:

```
select (case when substring_index(mycol, '://', -1) like '%/%'
             then substring_index(substring_index(mycol, '://', -1), '/', 1)
             when substring_index(mycol, '://', -1) like '%?%'
             then substring_index(substring_index(mycol, '://', -1), '?', 1)
             . . .   -- and so on for each character
             else substring_index(mycol, '://', -1) 
        end) as what_you_want
```

The `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]` is intended to be something like the valid character class for your domain names.

Comment: I do not get: In `order versions`, do you mean `older versions`? Anyways, I am using 6.3 so it is ok. But the challenge to capture the domain names characters. They are not just alphabetical characters. They contains numbers and dashes `-` if  I am correct.

Comment: Are you sure the `?` character in `LIKE` should be preceded by `\` as you write `%\?%` I looked at special characters in `LIKE` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) but it seems only the `%` and `_` should be escaped?? plz correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @user9371654 . . . `?` does not need to be escaped for `LIKE`.